mPDF QR Code not displaying in PDF using mpdf/qrcode library
I am using mPDF along with the mpdf/qrcode library to generate QR codes and embed them in PDF documents. These PDFs are generated from data extracted from XLS files using PHPSpreadsheet. The entire process of reading the XLS files and generating the PDFs works correctly, with the exception of displaying the QR code. Despite generating what appears to be a valid QR code image, it does not display in the final PDF. The PDF is generated with no errors reported by mPDF, but the area where the QR code should be appears blank.
I have tried two main methods to insert the QR code image into the PDF:

Direct Base64 encoding: I generate the QR code image as a PNG using mpdf/qrcode, then I encode it to Base64 and use the URI data:image/png;base64,.... inside the mPDF->Image() function.

use Mpdf\QrCode\QrCode;
use Mpdf\Output;

$qrCode = new QrCode($pdfUrl);
$output = new Output\Png();
$qrCodeImage = $output->output($qrCode, 300);
$mpdf->Image('data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($qrCodeImage), 10, 10, 40, 40);


Using a temporary file: I save the generated QR code image to a temporary file using tempnam() and file_put_contents(), and then use the file path with mPDF->Image(). After generating the PDF, I delete the temporary file.

use Mpdf\QrCode\QrCode;
use Mpdf\Output;

$qrCode = new QrCode($pdfUrl);
$output = new Output\Png();
$qrCodeImage = $output->output($qrCode, 300);

$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'qr');
file_put_contents($tempFile, $qrCodeImage);
$mpdf->Image($tempFile, 10, 10, 40, 40);
unlink($tempFile);

In both cases, the PDF is generated correctly, but the QR code does not appear. I have verified that the $pdfUrl variable contains the correct URL. I am using mPDF version 8.2.1, mpdf/qrcode version 1.2 and PHPSpreadsheet version 3.7, running on PHP 8.3.14. The data to generate the PDFs is correctly extracted from XLS files using PHPSpreadsheet, and the rest of the PDF content is generated without problems.
I have also tried adjusting the position and size parameters in mPDF->Image(), but this did not solve the problem. GD and mbstring extensions are enabled

Of course, you checked that the generated PNG is correct?

In fact you don't need to generate a PNG image. You can use Output\Mpdf to output the QR code directly to your Mpdf object.

I think Olivier's idea is viable, we can use Output\Mpdf to write the QR code directly to the PDF document, avoiding any PNG generation or base64 encoding:
use Mpdf\QrCode\QrCode;
use Mpdf\QrCode\Output\Mpdf as QrOutput;

// Make sure $pdfUrl is URL-encoded if it contains special characters
$qrCode = new QrCode($pdfUrl);
$output = new QrOutput();

// Parameters: QR code, mPDF instance, x position, y position, width (in mm)
$output->output($qrCode, $mpdf, 10, 10, 40);

